# kubernetes fluent-bit unable to resolve host

Tags: kubernetes, fluent-bit

### Issue Description

I am getting an error in fluent-bit basically saying it cant resolve host

```
getaddrinfo(host='<My Elastic Cloud Instance>.aws.elastic-cloud.com:9243', err=4): Domain name not found
```

I suspect it has something to do with the port getting appended in the dns lookup, but I can't seem to see any settings that join the two together in my configuration's

I have verified that using the a dnsutil pod in the same namespace, I am able to resolve the host correctly

### Info that may be helpful

Config Map output-elasticsearch.conf

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name            es
    Match           *
    Host            ${CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
    Port            ${CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
    Cloud_ID        ${CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_ID}
    Cloud_Auth      ${CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_USER}:${CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
    Logstash_Format On
    Logstash_Prefix kube1
    Replace_Dots    On
    Retry_Limit     False
    tls             On
    tls.verify      Off
```

elasticsearch-configmap

```
data:
  CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST: <MyCloudId>.aws.elastic-cloud.com
  CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_ID: >-
    elastic-security-deployment:<Bunch of Random Bits>
  CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT: '9243'
```

env portion of my daemonset

```
          env:
            - name: CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            - name: CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            - name: CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_ID
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_ID
            - name: CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-secret
                  key: CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_USER
            - name: CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-secret
                  key: CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
              value: elasticsearch
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
              value: '9200'
```

Comment: I was unable to get fluent-bit working, I modified the daemon to use a filebeat container, and modified its config and got that to work. I may at a different time come back and try to debug this more

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/4260

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you are using Elastic Cloud, try to decode the value of ${CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_ID} variable, remove the `:443` and encode it again.

I was getting this error and it was solved after doing this.

Comment: how to decode this ? @gabo

Comment: Hey @Sana.91, you can do it this way:


To decode:
```
$ echo "dXMtZWFzdC0xLmF3cy5mb3VuZC5pbyRhOGUwOTIyNTkzZmM0YjE2OWJlOWIyMDhhYjA4NTAxMSQwMWM2MzZhNjgxMGEY0MjM0ZjdiZQ==" | base64 -d

$ us-east-1.aws.found.io:443$a8e0922593fc4b169be9b2$01c0a4320980cfecf4234f7be
```

Remove the 443 and encode again:
```
$ echo "us-east-1.aws.found.io$a8e0922593fc4b169be9b208ab085011$01c636a6810a" | base64
$ dXMtZWFzdC0xLmF3cy5mb3VuZC5pb2M2MzZhNjgxMGEK
```

Comment: hey thanks :) .. i figured out

Answer (score 1):

For Elastic Cloud, try omit `Host` and `Port` from your output:

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name            es
    Match           *
    Cloud_ID        ${CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_ID}
    Cloud_Auth      ${CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_USER}:${CLOUD_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
    Logstash_Format On
    Logstash_Prefix kube1
    Replace_Dots    On
    Retry_Limit     False
    tls             On
    tls.verify      Off
```